# R Script Shiny ggplot() rearrange order

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good Morning

I have this code that works but it does not reorder the values:

```
  ggplot(dfm(), aes(fill=variable, y=web_name, x = value)) + 
    geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
    
    # add chart labels
    labs(title = paste(input$hometeamnameInput, " vs ", input$awayteamnameInput),
         subtitle = "Compare both teams",
         x = "xP per 90", y = NULL, caption = "") +
    # add my chart theme
    theme_ewen_rs(grid = "X", axis = FALSE, axis_text_size = 9, subtitle_size = 10,
                  plot_title_size = 14) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Recursive Light"))
```

When I add the reorder which I do have on other graphs it errors, eg here is one that works but does not have stack:

```
    ggplot(ah(), aes(x = reorder(web_name, form), y = form, color=position)) +
      geom_col(fill = ghibli_palettes$SpiritedMedium[4]) +
      coord_flip() +
      # add chart labels
      labs(title = paste(input$hometeamnameInput, " vs ", input$awayteamnameInput),
           subtitle = "Compare both teams",
           x = NULL, y = "xP per 90", caption = "") +
      # add my chart theme
      theme_ewen_rs(grid = "X", axis = FALSE, axis_text_size = 9, subtitle_size = 10,
                    plot_title_size = 14) +
      theme(axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Recursive Light"))
```

I have not been able to figure it out since altering the graph so its stackable

I would like it to reorder the graph output so the bars are order relative to there value